# Asegurar rutas bajo mismo firewall

Tags: regex, symfony2, access-control

Tengo una aplicacion symfony2 con una api rest y un backend de sonataAdmin.

En el archivo security.yml tengo lo siguiente:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        SONATA:
            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern:  /admin(.*)
            context:  user
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /admin/login
                use_forward: false
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                failure_path: null
            logout:
                path:    /admin/logout
            anonymous: true

        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token$
            security:   false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth$
            security:    false
            # Add your favorite authentication process here

        api:
            pattern:    ^/api(?!/user$)(?!/user/visit/)(?!/doc$) #con este patron todo api menos doc esta protegido
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  false # can be omitted as its default value

        main:
            pattern: .*
            context: user
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path: /login
                use_forward: false
                check_path: /login_check
                failure_path: null
            logout:  true
            anonymous: true

access_control:
    # url de fosuserbundle que debe ser disponible para usuarios anonimos
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #url de admin login necesita ser accesible sin credenciales
    - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    - { path: ^/admin, role: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/doc/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # url de api. Debe estar validado siempre.
    - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED ] }
```

Es decir, entre otras rutas, tengo la siguiente configuración de seguridad:

- rutas `/admin(.*)` protegidas bajo el firewall **`admin`**
- las rutas `^/api(?!/user$)(?!/user/visit/)(?!/doc$)` (todo lo que cuelgue de `/api`, menos `/api/user`, `/api/user/visit` y `/api/doc` están protegidos bajo **`oauth2`**.

Ahora me han pedido que la documentación de `/api` este protegida pero por el admin, de manera que si el usuario no está autentificado, se le dirija a `/admin/login`. Si está autentificado se le muestra la doc.

he cambiado el pattern de admin a lo siguiente:

```
(admin(.*))|(\/api\/doc(.*))
```

y el patrón de api queda así:

```
^/api(?!/user$)(?!/user/visit/)
```

Sin embargo, al acceder por navegador a `/api/doc`, si no estoy registrado, aparece la documentación. Se ve que no lanza la seguridad o hay algo que no estoy haciendo bien.

¿Alguien puede sugerirme alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una de las primeras cosas que se menciona en la [documentación](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html) es que:

> se utiliza la primera regla que coincida.

En tu `access_control`, el regex `^/*` coincide con cualquier ruta, por lo que todo lo que esté abajo de esta línea es irrelevante:

```
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**Deberías moverla al final**.

Además, supongo que para `/api/doc` debería ser `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` (***verificar*** qué rol debería ser).

```
    - { path: ^/api/doc/.*, role: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
```

---

Otras cosas a tener en cuenta

- **<kbd>Importante</kbd>** Todas tus expresiones deberían empezar con `^`.
  Un `^` coincide con el inicio de la ruta. Si se omite, expresiones como `/admin(.*)` pueden coincidir con rutas como `/blah/administracion-de-bienes`

- `(admin(.*))|(\/api\/doc(.*))` debería ser `^/(admin|api/doc)`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! llevaba dándole vueltas al tema de la expresión y me habia olvidado por completo del access_control (fallo mio). Por otra parte, es verdad que tengo algunas rutas sin el ^, (otras si que las tengo). Voy a ponerlas como seria correcto.